# Angular v3 and up/ error in Apply function when load HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I am trying to Load HTML dynamically (List and Text Box dynamically )  outside of angular 
from code side:  after loading the HTML by Jquery  I need to call  `scope.$apply()` .
as a user : the user will press Load Button and then the HTML will be loaded into page dynamically , everything is went fine as expected ,  however when  try  to select one of the value from the list, an error  will be displayed at the Browser console at the "apply" function   :
[image: Apply Error]
the demo of the code is below , 
I can see these error is just displayed when using Angular versions from 3 to 4.9 even 5 beta ...
however  when I use version 1.2.27 or less it is working without any error .
so how can you help solving this issue ? Is this a bug on the version 3 and up ?
Please : the code and the demo is below  however to see the error might you need to use debugger in the browser .

```js
var _app = angular.module("myapp", []);
var _ctrl = _app.controller("myctrl", ['$scope', '$window',
  function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.selectedFood = "1";
    $scope.quantity = "3"

  }
])

function add() {
  angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$compile',
    function($compile) {

      var sel = 'div[ng-controller="myctrl"]';

      var _html = "<input type='text' ng-model='quantity'><label>Select food</label><select ng-model='selectedFood'> <option value='0'>Banana</option><option value='1'>Apple</option><option value='2'>Orange</option><option value='3'>Tomato</option></select>";
      //angular.element(document.getElementById('test1')).scope().loaditems()
      var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("test1")).scope();

      $('#dvLoad').html($compile(_html)(scope));
      setTimeout(function() {
        scope.$apply();
      });

    }
  ]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" ng-app="myapp">
  <div id="test1" ng-controller="myctrl">

    <div id="dvLoad">
      Press the button to load Food List
      <input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Load" />
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code smells like it belongs in a directive, specifically in the `link` function.

Comment: @Makoto, Nope ,as you see  I just need to  load the HTML outside angular , (it is a part of project using ASP MVC & Angular )

Comment: Doesn't that error mean that you're calling `$apply()` when it's already in the cycle? Comment out the `$apply()` line and see what happens.

Comment: @Starscream1984, I need to use $apply() to execute the angular after loading the HTML Dynamically , if I commented the angular expression will not be evaluated , you can update the code and see the resul

Comment: Go to the link which is in the first line of your error messages and see what it says - if it is as I suspect, then somewhere, somehow, you are calling `$apply()` whilst it's already in a cycle and that is not allowed.

Comment: @Starscream1984 ,  the error  is saying ..$apply already in progress... However if you have a look at  my code (in the demo) I am calling "Apply" only one time outside the angular , and there is no other "Apply" and this error only at the version 3 and higher ,and cannot avoid calling this one time "Apply"  it is needed to execute the angular in Dynamica Loaded HTML.

Comment: `$apply()` runs all the time in the natural digest cycle of angular. If you explicitly call `$apply()` whilst it is already running as part of the digest cycle - you get this error. If you feel the manual `$apply()` is absolutely necessary, wrap it in a check `(!$scope.$$phase)`. Many consider this an anti-pattern though, I would prefer to figure out why my `$apply()` is being called when it is, to cause the error.